# Which decks are available in Trainer Challenge?

Tags: pokemon-tcg-online

When I play the Trainer Challenge, I can't pick certain decks that I have available through online battles.
In addition to that, I have 3 basic decks that are available in Trainer Challenge that I can't use elsewhere, specifically XY Basic Red, XY Basic Blue and XY Basic Green.

I'd like to know what determines in which mode I can use a certain deck? It probably has to do something with how the deck was acquired, but I couldn't find any concrete evidence to back this up.

Comment: Maybe split up the two questions. I have no knowledge at all about this game, but it seems that the two answers are related, but are completely separable answerable (and should be).

Comment: From my own experience, I believe that only standard decks can be used for trainer challenge (bought decks not assembled). To unlock the 3 basic decks for multiplayer use, I believe you need to unlock all cards for the deck (7 wins if I remember correctly). I may be wrong, but that was the conclusions I drew from my experience

Answer (score 2):

On trainer challenge you can only use Theme Decks (the decks you buy from the store) apart from the XY Basic.

That is kinda lame, because it would be nice to use your own decks. You can always test your decks using the test tool inside the deck building screen.

But anyway, this is done because you when win several matches with Theme decks, you unlock boosters and additional cards. Try winning all matches with one deck. You will unlock booster packs!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For 500 coins you can get a theme deck to use in trainer challenge. You also get decks by redeeming deck codes you buy IRL. I don't know if there is a list online of all compatible decks but some don't work, you unlock the cards but not a deck to use in Trainer Challenge. Let's play Eevee and Pikachu decks work for Trainer Challenge but I redeemed several tin decks and none worked. Mindbind Theme Deck works, which is odd because it's two separate 30 card decks that do NOT work well when used as one deck. I don't know of any list of which decks work and which don't for trainer challenge.